# PHP show image and video

Tags: php, apache, web

```
<?php
    $file = $_GET['path'];
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

    header('Content-type: '.finfo_file($finfo, $file));
    if(substr(finfo_file($finfo, $file), 0, 4) == "text")
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: text');
    else
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    @readfile($file);
?>
```

With this source code I can see image in my MBP but can't see image in my window desktop.
Instead of image it shows this to me: [image: http://cfile23.uf.tistory.com/image/202CC6224BD53DE30A2F05]
I use window 10, php7 and Apache 2.4 for my desktop. I found I have to include some modules to use `finfo_open` so I included it. However I can't understand why I can't get correct image

Also I want to play video with that code. However video doesn't played in both MBP and desktop. I can't find the reason can anyone help me plz?

Comment: finfo_open is a pain to use with windows, i would bet there is the problem. Were you able to load the magic database? To make that function work?

Comment: You said finfo_open is pain to use with windows. I can't understand what's the meaning. I can get mime type almost correctly? Isn't it enough? You want to say change that function to mime_content_type?

Comment: mmh okay then i guessed wrong. Use your browsers dev tools to compare the header. Try to add "Content-Disposition:"

Comment: I can't get any html contents in dev tools. Because I didn't create html file. I just execute that file

Comment: yeah but you still get the header back. In chrome for example open the dev tools go to network and reload the page then there should be one entry, click on it and you can see the header

Comment: I add `Content-disposion: inline` but still I can't see jpeg image.

Comment: try 'Content-Disposition', 'filename="' . $filename . '"'). Its a optional parameter but i dont have many information, so im just guessing

Comment: I added it but still I have same problem